# How does Picasso work when trying to load url from cache which is not cached and Network Policy offline?

Tags: android, picasso

```
Picasso.with(getApplicationContext())
                        .load(image_url)
                        .noFade()
                        .networkPolicy(NetworkPolicy.OFFLINE)
                        .into(_imgview);
```

This is my code with the call back I have written. Since this is horizontal listview of images it is loading previously cached image when next image has to load.

Here image is not cached so program calls error and I will load from network. In other case I am checking if it is cached then I will load from cache itself else network.

It is not triggering success or error ?
I don't know what's happening ?

Comment: If network policy is offline and image is not cached, how is it supposed to be display image ? Maybe it is not success or error, you should use placeholder.

Comment: Yes it should not display an image but don't know how it loads the previously cached image.